# why cannot dotnet ef tools find my installed dotnet sdk and runtime

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, dotnet-tool

I use a laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 under the active directory and domain policy. so I tried to install dotnet using snap, apt package manager, and even ./dotnet-install.sh but after all of those methods I am facing **the dotnet command is not found** when I am trying to run the `dotnet` command in my terminal.

So I installed dotnet manually on my laptop inside the home folder and it worked properly when I updated my PATH variable. but I am facing with this error:

> > $ **dotnet ef migrations add "MyMigrationName"**
>
> You must install .NET to run this application.
>
> App: /home/MyFolder/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef
> Architecture: x64
> App host version: 7.0.16
> .NET location: Not found
>
> Learn about runtime installation:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
>
> Download the .NET runtime:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.22.04-x64&apphost_version=7.0.16

How can I resolve this problem?